# Can't able to find a keyword in a File

Tags: c++, string, search, visual-c++, wdk

When I try to Find a Keyword from the GetLine() Function It only Returns a Empty String. But when I try to print the Line with std::cout, it prints everything, so i debugged the solution I found that the String is empty but std::cout somehow manages to print the lines in file.

```
 std::ifstream file(fileToSearch);
        std::string line;


        cout << endl << keyWords[i];
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
           
            cout << endl << keyWords[i]<<" ";
            cout << line;
            if (auto pos = line.find(keyWords[i]) != std::string::npos) {
                //   std::stringstream iss(line.substr(pos + keyWords[i].size()));
                cout << endl << "found again in String Table" << endl;
                //iss >> j;
                break;
            }

        }
```

This is the data in the File

```
%Checking Windows(R) Installer VersionConfiguring Windows InstallerConfiguring %s½Setup has completed configuring the Windows Installer on your system. The system needs to be restarted in order to continue with the installation. Please click Restart to reboot the system.%s
```

When I checked the Encoding of the file in Notepad++. I found that the file is not encoded at all , but when I changed the file to UTF-8 I can get the Value and Search It Successfully. Is there anyway to do this by code rather than changing it Manually??

[image: Look at the encoding here]

Comment: Yes you can, but first you need to understand (and describe) precisely what change notepad++ made to your file. Notepad++ does not have any 'not encoded at all' setting so I'm not sure exactly what you did. But in general converting string data between different encodings can be done.

Comment: I Clicked Convert to UTF-8 in the Encoding Toolbar and I could able to Search the keyword. But Before I clicked the Convert to UTF-8 It was not even Encoded in any Format.

Comment: But the question remains what encoding was it before you converted it to UTF-8? Obviously you need to know that before you can convert whatever it is to UTF-8. To be sure what the encoding is you need to look at the **byte values** of the bytes in the file and post those here.

Comment: It seems your file has some unusual characters in it, so to work out the encoding you need to know what byte (or bytes) are being used to represent those characters in your file before you ask notepad++ to convert to UTF-8. If you can determine that then post those byte values here.

Comment: Newbies often seem to forget that all a file ever contains is bytes, Any time that you see any program display those bytes as text, it is making some kind of interpretation of what those bytes mean. That is called the encoding. Until you can find out what encoding your file is using everything will just be guess work. There really is no such thing as 'not encoded at all'.

Comment: @john look at the image I uploaded in the question, only when I give convert to utf-8 or utf -16 I could able to search the keyword else I cannot. This is what I mean by it is not encoded.

Comment: Unfortunately the image does help much. I guess the blank menu in Notepad++ simply means that it doesn't recognise the encoding, there is no infallible way of determining a files encoding, So I can think of only two possibilities. 1) Where did you get the file from? Maybe that will give some clue as to the encoding. 2) Or, as I said before, I really need to see the **bytes** not the text to understand the encoding. Can you get a hex dump of the file? That should be enough.

Comment: The files does look a little strange, the `STX` byte in the middle, and the `NUL` bytes at the end. It's possible that it simply isn't encoded to any recognised standard. It's not a valid text file in other words, even though it contains some text within it.

Comment: Maybe the thing to concentrate on is why your code doesn't work on the original file, instead of trying to duplicate the undocumented process that Notepad++ uses when you ask it to convert to UTF-8. But again to understand that a hex dump of the file is needed.

Comment: Try `std::ifstream file(fileToSearch, std::ios::binary);`, see if that alters the outcome.